# Change application's Solr url with a master/slave configuration

Tags: asp.net, url, web, solr, replication

Im working in a "home project solr"(aka PoC), using Solr as search engine.
I'm using master/slave configuration in two distinct servers, so(in my plans) my search would be avaiable even if the main server comes down but, the problem is:

Im currently doing my search at url

```
http://mainSOLRSERVER:8080/search/select/?q=*:*
```

Is there any built-in solr component to check if this url is OK, and if is not, change to another server

```
http://redundancySOLRSERVER:8080/search/select/?q=*:*?
```

I aint using Solrj in my application, its a simple ASP.Net application using xml parsing in Solr's results.

The only thing I came up with, would be send a ping request to Solr's main server and, if returns not ok, build the request with the redundancy URL, but that would be necessary in every single search request, is that the right approach?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In production scenario, you would use a load balancer.

You don't need the ping. Directly execute the query on the main URL and if it returns an error, then query the backup URL. If that also throws error, then you are out of luck.